# how to fetch autogenerated document id in firebase firestore flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

// this is what ive tried.
it doesnt return the latest or last data ive added.

```
Future getData() async {
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    String formatted = formatter.format(now);
    final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final FirebaseUser user = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;

    QuerySnapshot qn = await db
        .collection('exams')
        .document(uid)
        .collection('intellective speed test')
        .document('sensorimotor')
        .collection('$formatted')
        .where('createdAt', isLessThan: Timestamp.now().toDate().toString())
        .getDocuments();

    return qn.documents;
  }
```

Comment: using native `DateTime` in the sorting should be fine. If you want to query the latest or last data, sort the field by descending and limit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get every document id from `DocumentSnapshot`

```
for (int i = 0; i < querySnapshot.documents.length; i++) {
  DocumentSnapshot docSnap = querySnapshot.documents.elementAt(i);
  final id = docSnap.documentID;
}
```

Or

```
querySnapshot.documents.forEach((docSnap) {
  final id = docSnap.documentID;
});
```